# How to remove slash from $http_referer variable

Tags: nginx, web, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I want to use NGINX as dynamic local CDN with proxy_pass based on Referer header and $http_refere variable. The problem is that the Referer (variable too) header contains a "/" at the end of the URL. I want to delete trailing slash in $http_referer. How can I do it?

My NGINX location:

```
location / {
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
  add_header Referrer-Policy 'strict-origin';
  proxy_pass $http_referer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it either via `if` block:

```
set $proxy $http_referer;
if ($http_referer ~ ^(.*)/$) { set $proxy $1; }
```

or via `map` directive:

```
map $http_referer $proxy {
    ~^(.*)/$  $1;
    default   $http_referer;
}
```

Then use the `$proxy` variable with the `proxy_pass` directive:

```
proxy_pass $proxy;
```